# Can't scroll page, depending on where your finger is

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, touch

I can't even explain how odd this is, so I have to link to the page: http://dev.mediaslave.ca/illustraflex/cameras.html

I did not post any code because I don't understand if this is a code issue, or a standard practice for HTML.

Basically, on that page there is a large linked image with a supporting caption DIV full of text and another link. Now on touch devices, if you place your finger on the image or Caption DIV and try and scroll the page, you can't. But if you touch somewhere other than that area (like the footer or header), you can scroll just fine.

WHAT.

So what I can't figure out is if this is a byproduct of the script, or are linked images sometimes unresponsive as a touch base?

There is definitely no answers for this that I could find on Google either.

If anyone can help out, i'd be very appreciative!

Comment: Tell your problem in one line,Dont understand properly your Question

Comment: @Jeff Monk has a site, which - on touchscreen devices - can not be scrolled when the finger is placed on the large background image.

Comment: If you put your finger on the elements on the page to scroll using a touch device, it doesn't scroll. If you touch somewhere else (menubar, footer), it does.

Thanks @Sam!

Comment: Nobody has any ideas? I did a search and didn't turn up anything...